# Difference between promenade and boardwalk

Tags: meaning, nouns, differences

What is the difference between the two above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A boardwalk is a type of promenade. There is many a promenade that is not a boardwalk, a [boardwalk](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/boardwalk) being:

> "a promenade made of wooden boards, usually along a beach or shore."

A perfect example is when young men and women go to prom, "prom" being short for "promenade." It is a rare prom that involves a boardwalk, a promenade made of wooden boards. Instead, the promenades involved often take place in marbled ballrooms, upon tiled stages, or even down a concrete stairway.

Another example is when I lived in Portugal. All along the beaches, or if not a beach town, along some point near the center of town, were promenades where it was tradition for the townsfolk to go every evening around 7pm to "pasear"-- to walk, mill about, and converse with one another. It was also traditon for these promenades to be made of stones-- specifically black and white stones forming intricate mosaics. They were never made of wooden boards, were never boardwalks.

Comment: There are also boardwalks that are not promenades. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boardwalk

Comment: _Boardwalk_ in the sense of a walkway along the seafront is a specifically American usage. So is _prom_ in the sense of a school dance (although I believe the custom has spread to the UK, it isn't such  a big thing over here).